# Отображение данных из нескольких массивов в динамические ячейки таблицы

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Есть несколько сущностей CoreData, объекты которых добавляются каждая в свой массив.
Объекты созданы на других экранах и благополучно отображаются каждые в своих таблицах. Задача отобразить их все в общей таблице. И каждое последнее добавление на других экранах должно быть первое в общей таблице... Не знаю, насколько правильно реализовано, поправьте, пожалуйста[image: Общая]

```
import UIKit
```

import CoreData

class CostsStoryViewController: BackgroundVC, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
let shared = CoreDataManager.shared
var fuelArray: [FuelCarStory] = []
var finesArray: [FinesStory] = []
var serviceArray: [ServiceStory] = []
var otherArray: [OtherCostsStory] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    
    let fetchRequestFuel = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "FuelCarStory")
    do {
        let results = try shared.context.fetch(fetchRequestFuel)
        for result in results as! [FuelCarStory] {
            fuelArray.append(result)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
    let fetchRequestFines = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "FinesStory")
    do {
        let results = try shared.context.fetch(fetchRequestFines)
        for result in results as! [FinesStory] {
            finesArray.append(result)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    let fetchRequestService = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "ServiceStory")
    do {
        let results = try shared.context.fetch(fetchRequestService)
        for result in results as! [ServiceStory] {
            serviceArray.append(result)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    let fetchRequestOther = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "OtherCostsStory")
    do {
        let results = try shared.context.fetch(fetchRequestOther)
        for result in results as! [OtherCostsStory] {
            otherArray.append(result)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return ???????????
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    ?????????
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FuelCommonCell", for: indexPath) as! FuelCommonCell

    let fuel = fuelArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.dateFuelLabel.text = fuel.dateFuelData
    cell.typeFuelLabel.text = fuel.typeFuelData
    cell.litersFuelLabel.text = fuel.numberOfLitersData
    cell.sumFuelLabel.text = fuel.amoutToFuelData
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вот так:

```
var entities: [(String, Int)] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    ...
    
    fuelArray.reverse()
    finesArray.reverse()
    serviceArray.reverse()
    otherArray.reverse()
    
    for i in 0 ..< fuelArray.count {
        entities.append(("fuel", i))
    }
    for i in 0 ..< finesArray.count {
        entities.append(("fines", i))
    }
    for i in 0 ..< serviceArray.count {
        entities.append(("service", i))
    }
    for i in 0 ..< otherArray.count {
        entities.append(("other", i))
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return entities.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch entities[indexPath.row].0 {
    case "fuel":
        let fuel = fuelArray[entities[indexPath.row].1]
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FuelCommonCell", for: indexPath) as! FuelCommonCell
        cell.dateFuelLabel.text = fuel.dateFuelData
        cell.typeFuelLabel.text = fuel.typeFuelData
        cell.litersFuelLabel.text = fuel.numberOfLitersData
        cell.sumFuelLabel.text = fuel.amoutToFuelData
        
        return cell
    case "fines":
        let fines = finesArray[entities[indexPath.row].1]
        
        ...
    case "service":
        let service = serviceArray[entities[indexPath.row].1]
        
        ...
    case "other":
        let other = otherArray[entities[indexPath.row].1]
        
        ...
    default:
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Только в общей таблице отображается одна запись из каждого массива, а нужно все...

Comment: Исправил ответ.